# Running a Low Magic RPG for beginners

Tags: gm-techniques, game-design

I'm running a campaign for a small group of friends- we're inexperienced with tabletop RPGs.  The campaign leans heavily on the story I've written and I wanted it to be more character driven than bogged down in half hour long combat sessions.

The game is set in a nascent low magic world.  The gods only just receded from the world after creating it and humanity as a whole is barely established; pretty much still nomadic tribes, hounded by demons since the gods' departure.

Last time I hacked together a home brew combat system I also had to guide all the character creation and I don't feel it was as engaging as it could've been.

How do I put together a solid stat/combat system for a low magic setting that plays quickly? Are there any RPGs that already meet this description?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. This question is likely to get closed as some combination idea-generating/game recommendation/primarily opinion-based. (Check the [tour] for more on topicality.) That said, I'm sure there are people in [chat] who have experience that could help and would be interested in hashing things out a bit. You'll need 20 rep to participate; I've just thrown you half of that with an upvote, and hopefully another'll come soon =)

Comment: Honestly, if you're not experienced with RPGs, I advise co-opting another system instead of trying to figure out all mechanics by yourself

Comment: The question in its current state is basically a game-reccomendation question which are off-topic here. Better alternatives would be "how to adapt game X for beginners", "how to run X in a low-magic setting", "when choosing a game, what criteria should I look for as a beginner GM", etc.